# Reloading the component with button click from another component in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have two components like app-root and new-component

I have a button in the app-root component. When I click on the button I need to reload the new-component each time.

Please guide me, how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily refresh your component from parent compopnent by creating a reload method inside component and calling from prent like below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <my-child #child ></my-child>
  <button (click)="child.refresh()" >Refresh Child</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'World'; 
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `<h1>Date : {{date}}</h1>`
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  date = new Date();
  
  refresh(){
    this.date = new Date();
  }
}
```

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h3079qXjKH5fxoJQW3C4?p=preview)!!